# how to write JavaScript function that contains at least ten comma separated values between 1 and 100 (inclusive). and test it to do some math?

Tags: javascript

The user is required to enter 10 comma separated numbers between 1-100 .
Ex\ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, or more will be good, if the comma less than ten //alart("comma should be ten or more and the number should be from 1 to 100 not less or more")

Comment: This sounds like a homework question that you have made no attempt to solve or debug. Please read https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/73574

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add some codes to your post, show us what you've tried so far.

Here's a sample code, not 100% what you want, but you've got a start-up

```js
var user_input= "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11";
var comma_count = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < user_input.length; i++) {
   if (user_input[i] === ','){
     comma_count = comma_count + 1;
   }
 }

if (comma_count < 10) {
 alert('less than 10');
}
```

Make sure to read the javascript docs and search through Stack Overflow for others topics related to your question

Answer (score 0):

You can split the values by comma from the string, count the length first, then check every member whether it satisfy the condition one-by-one.

```js
function check(user_input) {
  var check1 = true;
  var splitted = user_input.split(',');
  if (splitted.length !== 10) {
    return false;
  }
  splitted.forEach(item => {
    var parsedInt = parseInt(item, 10);
    if (parsedInt < 1 || parsedInt > 100){
      check1 = false;
      return false;
    }
  });
  
  return check1;
}

function specialAlert(arr){
  if(!check(arr))
    alert("comma should be ten or more and the number should be from 1 to 100 not less or more")
}

var user_input= "1,2,3,4,5,6,100,7,8,9,10,11";
var user_input1= "1,2,3,4,5,6,101,7,8,9,20";
var user_input2= "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";

specialAlert(user_input);
specialAlert(user_input1);
specialAlert(user_input2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `split()` the input string by `,` and check the `length` of the resulting array. If more than 10 tokens are found, the input string had at least 10 commas.

Then use [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to do the range check. The method will return `false` as soon as an element that does not satisfy the range condition is found, or `true` otherwise.

```js
const inputs = [
  '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11', // OK
  '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10', // not more than 10
  '-10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11', // negative
  '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,110', // more than 100
  'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k' // not a number
];

inputs.forEach(input => console.log(input, test(input)));

function test(input) {
  let nums = input.split(',');
  return nums.length > 10 &&
         nums.every(num => num >= 1 && num <= 100);
}
```